# How to retrieve samples from the database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, rdbms

Suppose I have many tagged entities (e.g. blog posts with tags) to store in a SQL database. For example:

```
post1: work
post2: work, programming, java, work
post3: work, programming, sql
post4: vacation, photo
post5: vacation
post6: photo
```

Suppose also I have a list of tags

```
work, vacation
```

Now I'd like to get a posts *sample* of size 2, i.e. two posts with tags from the list. For example

```
sample1: post1 and post2
sample2: post1 and post4
sample3: post2 and post5
```

In addition I'd like the *sample* to contain all tags in the list. Note that `sample1` does not meet this requirement since the set of tags of the sample entities does not contain tag `vacation` from the list.

I would like also all tags occurrences to be equal. Let's consider 2 samples of size 4.

```
sample1: post1, post2, post3, post6
sample2: post1, post3, post4, post5
```

Note that `sample1` does not meet this requirement since tag `work` occurs 3 times in it and `vacation` occurs only once.

My question is: how to design a relational database and SQL query to retrieve samples of given size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all posts that have tags in a comma delimited list:

```
select postid
from post_tags
where find_in_set(tagid, @LIST) > 0
group by postid
having count(distinct tagid) = 1+length(@LIST) - length(replace(',', @LIST, ''));
```

If you want just a "sample" of them:

```
select postid
from (select postid
      from post_tags
      where find_in_set(tagid, @LIST) > 0
      group by postid
      having count(distinct tagid) = 1+length(@LIST) - length(replace(',', @LIST, ''))
     ) t
order by rand()
limit 5
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain this `having count(distinct tagid) = 1+length(@LIST) - length(replace(',', @LIST, ''))` thing ?

Comment: @Michael . . . That is counting the number of elements in the string.  It is the number commas plus one.